# Text on image at the point of touch

Tags: android, image, touch

I need to apply some text on the X,Y coordinates of the image where a touch event is occurred. Its just like the Image Tagging on facebook. So every time a touch is occurred, user can put some text in txtview at the touch point.

What I've done so far is that I am loading image from gallery and showing it on image viewer.

```
public class LoadImg extends Activity  {
private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;
int x,y;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    x=0;y=0;
    String picturePath = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getString("picturePath", "");
    if(!picturePath.equals(""))
    {
       ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
       imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
    }

    Button buttonLoadImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    buttonLoadImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Intent i = new Intent(
                    Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                     android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

            startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
        }
    });
}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent  data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null  != data) {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit().putString("picturePath", picturePath).commit();
        cursor.close();
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));

           }  }
```

Also implementing OnTouchListener, I am trying this code but not working. Any help .

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    x=(int) event.getX();
    y=(int) event.getY();
    imageshow();
    return true;    
}
private void imageshow() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(x!=0 && y!=0)
    {
     TextView tv=new TextView(this);
     LinearLayout.LayoutParams trparams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        tv.setLayoutParams(trparams);
    tv.layout(x, y, 0, 0);

    }
}
```

Something like [this](http://www.thinglink.com/scene/465473253519917057)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I understood from the question is, You have an image view and where ever we touches upon the image, you need a text there. 
I done this using `FrameLayout`.

First of all, I wrapped the ImageView with a FrameLayout as

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_marginTop="98dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
        android:src="@drawable/old1" />

</FrameLayout>
```

This is not a must, to be a FrameLayout. **Just wrap the image with some layout**.

Then inside MainActivity, I done as

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
FrameLayout layout;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    layout=(FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.frameLayout1);
    layout.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
             int x=(int) event.getX();
              int  y=(int) event.getY();
              Log.d("Nzm", "x="+x+"y="+y);
                FrameLayout mFrame=new FrameLayout(MainActivity.this);
                 TextView tv=new TextView(MainActivity.this);

                if(x!=0 && y!=0)
                {
                    FrameLayout.LayoutParams mParams=new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                    mFrame.setLayoutParams(mParams);
                    mFrame.setPadding(x, y, 0, 0);
                    tv.setLayoutParams(mParams);
                    tv.setText("Tooltip");
                    mFrame.addView(tv);
                    layout.addView(mFrame);
                }
            return true;
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: Thnx .. but this way a static text would appear (Tooltip) everytime a touch occurred. I want something like user can add a different text on each touch . Is this possible ??

Comment: Instead of TextView, you can create any view according to your need.

Comment: That would be so long and inappropriate for the current question. Better ask it as an another question. Also, don't forget to mark this answer if it was useful :)

Comment: You done it:) Also, consider marking on your older questions also.

Comment: Accepted answer of this link is working fine https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36812567/android-draw-text-on-imageview-with-finger-touch